# How do I convert a numeric number to a customized text string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of numeric duration values:

```
1:00:00
3:00:00
2:30:00
4:45:00
```

that I would like to convert into text string values in a certain format:

xxh yym (h=hours, m=minutes)

So the above should look like:

```
1h 00m
3h 00m
2h 30m
4h 45m
```

I need to solve this preferably with a formula so I can convert 8k rows.
What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: how do you want to convert 26:50:25 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an array formula and the `TEXT()` method:

`=arrayformula(text(A1:A, "h\h mm\m"))`

Just replace `A1:A` with the range of time values you would like to convert.

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 0):

Well quick go at this:
[image]

But there are other ways.